# Line integral along the paths $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$

Tags: integration, geometry

We let $F :\mathbb R^3\rightarrow\mathbb R^3$ be vector field given by:
$$F(x,y,z)=(x^2,0,y^2)$$

and we let $\gamma_1,\gamma_2:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ be two paths from $(0, 0, 0)$ to $(1, 1, 1)$ defined as:
$$\gamma_1(t)=(t,t^2,t^3), \gamma_2(t)=\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right), 1-\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right),t\right)$$
And then I have to evaluate the line integral $W_F(\gamma_i)$ of F along the paths $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$. I'm not sure how to find and define $\vec{r}'(t)$. Normally I just will find $r(t)=(1-t)(0,0,0)+t(1,1,1)=(t,t,t)$, but that will not be true here while we have $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$. But how can I write down the line integral here? I can see how to deal with $\gamma_1(t)$ and $\gamma_2(t)$? Hope anyone can help me?

Comment: What is the relevance of $G$ in your question?

Comment: What is $\vec r'(t)$?

Comment: G is not relevant here, it was just relevant for a further question, so yes I just delete it

Comment: For the first path, $r(t) = (t, t^2, t^3), 0 \leq t \leq 1$ as you are going from $(0, 0, 0)$ to $(1, 1, 1)$. $r'(t) = (1, 2t, 3t^2)$ Similarly check for the second path.

Comment: Eliot G, yes that the big question, can you help me?

Comment: Math Lover, so for the second path we get $r'(t)=(\frac{\pi cos(\pi \cdot t/2)}{2},\frac{\pi sin(\pi \cdot t/2)}{2},1)$? But how can I use this?

Comment: yes and again $0 \leq t \leq 1$ given the start and end points So you need to use the usual method: Find dot product $F(r(t)) \cdot r'(t) ~ dt$ and then integrate

Comment: Btw if you are specifically writing something to me, you must tag using @userid otherwise we do not get the notification..

Comment: @Math Lower:So I sum the two integrals together, the one for the first path and the one for the second path?

Comment: No you do not sum up. You need to evaluate line integrals across both paths separately and you get two results.

Comment: Oh okay I see, so I just find both of them and that is my answer?

Comment: yes.............................

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help, I will try that